# Graph activity from logs on a timeline

Tags: microsoft-excel, logging

With an input of a large list of timestamps representing some activity occurring over time, I'd like to have a visual graph or representation of frequency (either clusters of thin lines, or a line graph representing number of occurrence over time).

What is the easiest way to achieve this output using excel?

Comment: It somewhat depends on what you want to visualize.  If you want time to be treated as a variable, the simplest output would be to add a data column containing a value, like 1, for each entry.  Plotting the raw data as a scatter diagram would plot the points along the "1" line and you would see "density" of dots, illustrating the distribution over time.  You could use Excel's built-in histogram feature to count occurrences at a set interval, then plot the histogram, which would look more like a typical graph.

Comment: I'm looking to get a visual representation of the time scale, so the x axis would have a fix time interval, and the data points would show up when they occur, with space between them equal to the time gap between the events. I'll experiment with histogram.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Timeline chart in Excel](http://superuser.com/questions/149791/timeline-chart-in-excel)